# jquery.data returning json string instead of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, erb

I am rendering json into an html data attribute and using jquery.data to read the attribute.  I am expecting $('[data-attribute]').data('attribute') to parse the json and return an object but it intermittently returns a string instead.

**location.html.erb**

```
<div data-location="<%= render 'location_json' %>">
```

**location_json.erb**

```
<%= @location.to_json(
      only: [:id, :name, :lat, :lng],
      method: [:display_name]) %>
```

**location.js**

```
var location = $('[data-location]').data('location')
```

I suspect an encoding/escaping problem, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ERB was intermittently adding newlines which resulted in a json string that jquery.data wouldn't parse. For example, this parsed correctly:

```
<div data-location="{name&quot;:&quot;Bandido&#x27;s&quot;}">
```

But this did not (note trailling double quote on newline):

```
<div data-location="
{name&quot;:&quot;Bandido&#x27;s&quot;}
">
```

To prevent ERB from adding newlines, add a dash before the closing ERB tag

```
-%>
```

Solution:

```
<div data-location="<%= render 'location_json' -%>">
```